# Keeping a cursor alive in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

By default Mongo cursors die after 10 minutes of inactivity. I have a blank cursor that I eventually want to run though the whole database but there will be times of inactivity for over 10 minutes. I need a way to keep this alive to I can keep calling it.

Setting the expiry time completely off is not an option. If this program crashes it will cause cursors to linger in the databases memory which is not good. Also occasionally calling .next() during my other stuff does not work as the batch sizes are set fairly high to get good performance on the other parts of the code that are calling the cursor a lot.

I tried just periodically calling cursor.alive to see if that sent a signal to Mongo that would keep the cursor active but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a smaller batch size. This will cause activity and you should not hit the 10 minute timeout.

```
for doc in coll.find().batch_size(10):
```

Alternatively you can set `timeout=False` when calling `find` (this could lead to issues when the cursor is not manually closed):

```
for doc in coll.find(timeout=False)
```